# Ffmpeg program has memory problems when translating from AV_PIX_FMT_YUV422P format

Tags: c++, video, ffmpeg, valgrind, libav

I wrote a translation method for changing the pixel format and found strange behavior. If I translate from the AV_PIX_FMT_YUV422P format to AV_PIX_FMT_YUV420P then I have a lot of warnings from the valgrind like:

```
==128396== Use of uninitialised value of size 8
==128396==    at 0x4A172F5: ff_hyscale_fast_mmxext (hscale_fast_bilinear_simd.c:207)
==128396==    by 0x48E1E3E: lum_h_scale (hscale.c:54)
==128396==    by 0x49EA06F: swscale (swscale.c:466)
==128396==    by 0x49EC9C9: sws_scale (swscale.c:986)
==128396==    by 0x1092DF: avframeToCvmat(AVFrame*, AVPixelFormat, AVFrame*, int) (main.cpp:38)
==128396==    by 0x1093CD: main (main.cpp:65)
```

But if I translate from AV_PIX_FMT_BGR24 to AV_PIX_FMT_YUV420P, then everything goes without valgrind warning.

What could be the problem?

Code:

```
extern "C"
{
    #include <libswscale/swscale.h>
    #include <libavformat/avformat.h>
    #include <libswresample/swresample.h>
    #include <libavutil/pixdesc.h>
    #include <libavutil/imgutils.h>
}

void changePxlFormat(AVFrame *src, AVPixelFormat dstPixelFormat, AVFrame *dst, int align) {
    AVFrame *newFrame = dst;

    dst->format = dstPixelFormat;
    dst->width = src->width;
    dst->height = src->height;
    dst->colorspace = src->colorspace;
    dst->pict_type = src->pict_type;

    if (av_frame_get_buffer(newFrame, align) != 0) {
        if (!dst) {
            av_frame_free(&newFrame);
        }
        return;
    }

    SwsContext *conversion = sws_getContext(src->width,
                                            src->height,
                                            (AVPixelFormat)src->format,
                                            src->width,
                                            src->height,
                                            dstPixelFormat,
                                            SWS_FAST_BILINEAR,
                                            nullptr,
                                            nullptr,
                                            nullptr);

    sws_scale(conversion, src->data, src->linesize, 0, src->height, dst->data, dst->linesize);

    sws_freeContext(conversion);
}

int main()
{
    int width = 640;
    int height = 480;
    AVFrame *pBGRFrame = NULL;

    pBGRFrame = av_frame_alloc();
    uint8_t *pszBGRBuffer = NULL;
    int nBGRFrameSize;

    AVPixelFormat srcPxlFormat = AV_PIX_FMT_YUV422P;

    nBGRFrameSize = av_image_get_buffer_size(srcPxlFormat, width, height, 1);

    pszBGRBuffer = (uint8_t *)av_malloc(nBGRFrameSize);
    av_image_fill_arrays(pBGRFrame->data, pBGRFrame->linesize, pszBGRBuffer, srcPxlFormat, width, height, 1);
    pBGRFrame->format = srcPxlFormat;
    pBGRFrame->width = width;
    pBGRFrame->height = height;

    AVFrame *dst = av_frame_alloc();

    changePxlFormat(pBGRFrame, AV_PIX_FMT_YUV420P, dst, 0);

    av_free(pszBGRBuffer);
    av_frame_free(&dst);
    av_frame_free(&pBGRFrame);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you use a debug build of libswscale.so.5.4.100? That will give you more info as to what is happening.

Comment: @PaulFloyd I've already used debug build. If this were not the case, valgrind wouldn't show the name of the method called in libswscale.so.5.4.100.

Comment: I would expect a debug build to give you the file and line within libswscale.so not just the function name. It looks to me as if your library is not stripped but does not have debuginfo either.

Comment: @PaulFloyd I rebuild correctly the libraries and fixed the valgrind output.

Comment: Now that you have the source info you either need to read it or use a debugger to see what is happening. You could also run your application under vgdb, the valgrind remote debugger.